# ReactJS route URL generating by config

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs

Let's say I have this App code

```
const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <nav>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            <Link to="/about">Contact</Link>
        </nav>
    )
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Menu/>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/contact" render={() =>
                    <h1>Contact</h1>
                } />
                <Route path="/about" render={() =>
                    <h1>About</h1>
                } />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

All I want to know is how to make route paths non-static and base the whole route tree on some kind of config.

Lets say that I would like to change `/about` route path to `/about_us`. In that case, I need to search the whole project for `/about` string and properly replace it. That would not be the optimistic way when the project would be rather big.

What if I had some routing config stored in constant and some kind of function which generates the whole path on the basis of some data like route name and query parameters. For example:

```
const ROUTES = {
    home : '/',
    page: '/page/:pageid',
    about: '/about'
};

const url = (routeName, routeParams) => {
    // here generate route for particular route name
};
```

Then I could change my JSX like this:

```
<Link to={ url('contact') }>Contact</Link>
```

So, with change on the `ROUTES` constant, all routes path generated with `url()` function also will change.

My question is: 
**Is there any good existing solution / practise / pattern / package for that kind of problems**?

*(btw. just learning ReactJS)*

And then anouther question appears. What with ReactJS application modulatity. How to divide route config to be stored only within particular module (for example: posts routes config in "Blog" module).

Comment: i assume you are using react-router? if so this can come handy https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late but just in case anybody wants a strongly typed version which uses react-router:

```
import { generatePath } from "react-router";

const generateRoutes = (routes) => {
  return Object.keys(routes).reduce((agg, next) => {
    agg[next] = {
      path: routes[next],
      to: (params) => generatePath(routes[next], params)
    };
    return agg;
  }, {});
};

export const Routes = generateRoutes({
  home: "/",
  contactUs: "/contact-us",
  blogPost: `/blog-post/:id`,
  products: `/products/:category(A|B|C)/:sort(ASC|DESC)?`,
});

console.log(Routes.home.path) // outputs: /
console.log(Routes.contactUs.to()) // outputs: /contact-us
console.log(Routes.products.to({category: "A", sort: "ASC"})) // outputs: /products/A/ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't write your own ? The simple one may looks like this

```js
// CLASS
class AppRoutes {
    constructor(routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }

    path(name) {
        return this.routes[name]
    }

    to(name, ...params) {
        const regex = /:[^\/:]+/;
        let path = this.routes[name],
            i = 0,
            result;
        while(result = regex.exec(path)) {
            path = path.replace(result[0], params[i])
            i++
        }
        return path;
    }
}


// USAGE
var appRoutes = new AppRoutes({
    home: '/',
    about: '/about',
    post: '/posts/:byUser/:id',
})

console.log( 
  appRoutes.path('about') 
)

console.log(
  appRoutes.to('post', 'John', 'somepostId')
)
```

Comment: Surely I thought about this. Needed to ask whether this type of solution exist, to not to write it again from the beginning (if not) ^^. Second thing is standards and best practises - don't know very much as a React begineer - best to use proper things from the start :). Thanks for the answer.